# Decrypt input parameter in Lambda function in AWS Codepipeline

Tags: encryption, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, amazon-kms

I built a CodePipeline with a CodeBuild step that generates as output a file "build.json" with a single line tag information. This file is the input for a next Lambda step in the Codepipeline. The Lambda function wants to read the tag information and then do something with it. Therefore I read the S3 object with s3::getobject and as response I get:

```
{
"AcceptRanges": "bytes",
"LastModified": "2017-08-07T00:25:22.000Z",
"ContentLength": 158,
"ETag": "\"4444a193ad79ffe0ec0bd51ce7cf297c\"",
"ContentType": "",
"ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms",
"Metadata": {
    "codebuild-content-sha256": "fa85881e29d5b68464b078243ac23754189741e244bbf2d3748c02d97885ff51",
    "codebuild-content-md5": "44444449e8f4b830a487b86e1e94c0"
},
"SSEKMSKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:813287844011:key/4444444-0db2-4c3c-b24e-20ff7bbe206a",
"Body": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
        80,
        75,
        3,...]}}
```

when I use the content and send it to kms to decrypt like:

```
kms.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob: mydata.Metadata["codebuild-content-sha256"]  }, function (err, kmsData) {
if (err) {
    console.log("ERROR " + err);
} else {
    console.log("SUCCESS"); 
}
```

I only get: ERROR InvalidCiphertextException: null.

I also tried to provide some of the other values as Encryptioncontext, but had no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the object encrypted with another KMS key itself other than the S3 server side encryption? In my understanding, the data returned by S3:GetObject is decrypted, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/serv-side-encryption.html